# C++ Put string in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I keep seeing similar questions to mine, however, I can't seem to find one that helps my situation. Honestly, it seems like such a mundane question, I shouldn't be asking it, but here I am 2 weeks latter, still with no answer.

```
{
    string word;
    ArrayWithWords[d] = word;
    d++;
}
```

Every time this loop runs, I want to put **word** in position **d** of the array. Other examples I've found only turn the string into char*.

The array will be used more than once and having a solid value, if that's what it's called, is far more preferred. I'd like to avoid using a pointer.

Comment: Can you clarify how ArrayWithWords was declared? Also, are you running into an error or anything? What kind of loop are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a vector of strings.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> ArrayWithWords(10);
  size_t d = 5; // something between 0 and 9

  std::string word;
  ArrayWithWords[d] = word;
  d++;
}
```

Comment: ...Completely forgot about those... Even have some code using them... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same thing that was just posted but a little bit more old school.

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string stringArray[10];

  string word;
  word = "hello";

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
      stringArray[i] = string(word);
  }
}
```